# Catching application context error spring junit

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-boot, spring-test

I am writing junits for my spring boot based application, and my beans depends on some configuration parameters specified in application-.properties.
In my configuration class where I am generating beans,

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig{

@Value("${MyProperty}")
private String myProperty;

@Bean
public myBean bean1() throws MyException{
  if(myProperty.contentEquals("abc"){
     throw MyException("Value abc not allowed for bean1");
  }
}
```

In my junit I want to detect this scenario , if in my junit I set the profile and run it errors out saying 'Application startup failed' and not reach my before method or test method.

How do I handle this so that the junit does not fail and I am able to detect the myexception as well.
Basically what I need is the application context creation to fail, but my unit tests to pass.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> *beans depends on some configuration parameters specified in application-.properties*

This can be controlled  by the `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation directly on your bean definition. Therefore instead of throwing an exception in your test bean, you won't have it registered at all provided your config is not there:

I am writing junits for my spring boot based application, and my beans depends on some configuration parameters specified in application-.properties. In my configuration class where I am generating beans,

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "myProperty", havingValue = "'hiThere'")
@Bean
public myBean bean1() {
   //..
}
```

If you want to invoke some `SpEL` operation on the property you can use `@ConditionalOnExpression`:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("${myProperty}.contains('ere')")
@Bean
public myBean bean1() {
   //..
}
```

Comment: I understand the conditional on property annotation, thanks for your suggestion.

But this opens up another issue that application starts even with the bean not created. I should not let that happen. 
That from my understanding is only possible by throwing an exception in bean factory method.
That is what I am doing currently in my code.In my unit test can I detect that ?

Comment: in that case you ll have to start the context in your test method directly in order to detect the exception

Comment: Can you suggest how ? I use SpringRunner for my unit tests.